# HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 32. Did you forget to register an adapter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-hive

I'm trying to create a try Hive database and facing some issues I can't solve.

my model is

```dart
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class Tasks {
  @HiveField(0)
  final String task;

  @HiveField(1)
  final bool isCompleted;

  Tasks({required this.task, required this.isCompleted});
}
```

and the file generated by hive_generator

```dart
class TasksAdapter extends TypeAdapter<Tasks> {
  @override
  final int typeId = 1;

  @override
  Tasks read(BinaryReader reader) {
    final numOfFields = reader.readByte();
    final fields = <int, dynamic>{
      for (int i = 0; i < numOfFields; i++) reader.readByte(): reader.read(),
    };
    return Tasks(
      task: fields[0] as String,
      isCompleted: fields[1] as bool,
    );
  }

  @override
  void write(BinaryWriter writer, Tasks obj) {
    writer
      ..writeByte(2)
      ..writeByte(0)
      ..write(obj.task)
      ..writeByte(1)
      ..write(obj.isCompleted);
  }

    @override
  int get hashCode => typeId.hashCode;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      identical(this, other) ||
      other is TasksAdapter &&
          runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
          typeId == other.typeId;
}
```

in my `main()`:

```dart
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  Hive.init(directory.path);

  Hive.registerAdapter(TasksAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Tasks>("TheList");

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I also tried lazy open but the same error is showing in debugging.

my installed dependencies are:
`hive: ^2.0.4`
`hive_flutter: ^1.1.0`
`path_provider: ^2.0.5` and
`build_runner: ^2.1.2`
hive_generator: ^1.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is replacing the `Hive.init();` with `Hive.initFlutter();` from hive_flutter package.

So, the code would be:

```dart
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final document = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  await Hive.initFlutter(document.path);
  Hive.registerAdapter(TodoAdapter());
  await Hive.openBox<Todo>('todos');
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I noticed the same happened when i changed a typeId. I fixed mine by deleting the app from my phone and running it again, sort of like clearing the cache.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

This error comes up for a handful of reasons. To start, I would try to import [hive_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/hive_flutter):

`import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';`

And then call `await Hive.initFlutter();` before opening any boxes.

Also, you can wrap your registerAdapter call in an if statement:

```
if (!Hive.isAdapterRegistered(1)) {
    Hive.registerAdapter(TasksAdapter());
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was that I opened a Hive box before registering the type adaptor. According to Hive's official docs:

> It's recommended to register all `TypeAdapters` before opening any boxes.

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning the Flutter project resolved my problem.

In manu: Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Clean

Answer (score 0):

Hive.initFlutter(); fine But

In my case I had classes composition

and i was missing **adding adapter** to class **B**

```
@HiveType(typeId: 1)
class A{. B data;}
@HiveType(typeId: 2)
class B{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have introduced two different adapters in another branch and registered those there. After I switched to another branch (in which the adapter were not present) and ran the code. It gave me this error as it was still looking for other typeIds. Quick resolution is to **delete the app** from the device/emulator and run the application from scratch as it will clear the storage.

Alternative you try following code

```
Hive.deleteFromDisk()
```

Or

```
box.clear()
```

If your are interested you can also perform migration using something like this:

```
Hive.box("myBox", version: 5, 
migrator: (oldVersion, newVersion, box) async {
  await box.delete("unusedKey");
  await box.put("newKey", 7);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app from the device and reinstall that fixed my issue

Answer (score -1):

Just register the HiveAdapter in your main.dart and boom!

```
Hive.registerAdapter(WeekendDayCollectionAdapter());
```

Answer (score -2):

1. typeId starts from 0, not 1
2. delete app from mobile device and rerun flutter worked for m

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually, this worked for me. (Deleting the app from the emulator and rerunning the app).
That is because somewhere the installed app is still using the old adapter settings.