Unhandled Exception: HiveError: Cannot read, unknown typeId: 36. Did you forget to register an adapter?
I'm encountering an error in my Flutter application related to Hive. I attempted to resolve it by adding await Hive.initFlutter();, but that did not work. Additionally, I don't have any Hive model with a type ID of 36; I only have 18 models, each with its own type ID.

Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259338/hiveerror-cannot-read-unknown-typeid-32-did-you-forget-to-register-an-adapte

I tried every thing on that thread. I don't have a model from type Id 36.
